# how to best visualize CNN architecture? (experience using "PlotNeuralNet")

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, visualization

I'm writing a thesis and want to present a visualisation of the CNN architecture used for the analysis (written in PyTorch). I came across this cool repository [PlotNeuralNet](https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet) with examples for how to generate LaTeX code for drawing neural networks for reports and presentation. However, I'm having trouble finding out how to exactly define my particular architecture.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet/blob/master/pyexamples/test_simple.py) of how one would define an architecture.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from pycore.tikzeng import *

# define your arch

arch = \[
    to_head( '..' ),
    to_cor(),
    to_begin(),
    to_Conv("conv1", 512, 64, offset="(0,0,0)", to="(0,0,0)", height=64, depth=64, width=2 ),
    to_Pool("pool1", offset="(0,0,0)", to="(conv1-east)"),
    to_Conv("conv2", 128, 64, offset="(1,0,0)", to="(pool1-east)", height=32, depth=32, width=2 ),
    to_connection( "pool1", "conv2"),
    to_Pool("pool2", offset="(0,0,0)", to="(conv2-east)", height=28, depth=28, width=1),
    to_SoftMax("soft1", 10 ,"(3,0,0)", "(pool1-east)", caption="SOFT"  ),
    to_connection("pool2", "soft1"),  
    to_Sum("sum1", offset="(1.5,0,0)", to="(soft1-east)", radius=2.5, opacity=0.6),
    to_connection("soft1", "sum1"),
    to_end()
\]

def main():
    namefile = str(sys.argv[0]).split('.')[0]
    to_generate(arch, namefile + '.tex' )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, looking at the different available blocks available in pycore module, I'm still not able to use the tool. Documentation for usage is not really that elaborate, so I was hoping someone here would find it trivial to define the architecture below. Else, any good ways to

```
class Net20(nn.Module): 
    """ CNN for 20-day Image 
    This particular model should have:
    - 3 blocks
    - 64 layers in first block, multiply by 2 each subsequent block
    - filter size (5,3)
    - vertical stride = 3 (but only in first layer)
    - vertical dilation = 2 (but only in first layer)
    - Leaky Relu activation function
    - max pooling (2,1) at the end of each block
    """ 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            Conv2dSame(1, 64, kernel_size=(5,3), stride=(3,1), dilation=(2,1)),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01, inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d((2, 1), ceil_mode=True)
        )
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
            Conv2dSame(64, 128, kernel_size=(5,3)),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01, inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d((2, 1), ceil_mode=True)
        )
        self.layer3 = nn.Sequential(
            Conv2dSame(128, 256, kernel_size=(5,3)),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01, inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d((2, 1), ceil_mode=True)
        )
        self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
            nn.Linear(46080, 1), 
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.reshape(-1,1,64,60)
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        x = self.layer3(x)
        x = x.reshape(-1,46080)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        return x
```

Comment: I found this before on LinkedIn, https://www.linkedin.com/posts/philipvollet_datascience-deeplearning-machinelearning-activity-6980414758407577600-Jk_D?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop, they can visualize CNNs based on LeNet architecture. It may help

Answer (score 0):

You can try `model.summary()` or `keras.utils.plot_model`. You may want to check: https://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-deep-learning-neural-network-model-keras/